Regularity and decay of Fourier-like series on a manifold
Let $D$ be a first-order self-adjoint elliptic differential operator acting on sections of a vector bundle $S$ over a closed manifold $M$. Then it is well-known that the various eigenspaces $E_\lambda$ (which by elliptic regularity consist of smooth sections of $S$) of $D$ provide a decomposition of $L^2(S)$ in the sense that
$$L^2(S)=\overline{\bigoplus_{\lambda\in\sigma(D)}E_\lambda},$$
where the direct sum is orthogonal. Thus each section $s\in L^2(S)$ can be written
$$s=\sum_\lambda s_\lambda,$$
where $s_\lambda$ is the orthogonal projection of $s$ onto $E_\lambda$.
In John Roe's book "Elliptic operators, topology and asymptotic methods", there is a nice characterisation of the smooth part of $L^2(M)$ via the following proposition:

with the following proof (which is the source of my confusion):

Here the Sobolev space $W^k$ is defined via the norm
$$\|u\|_k^2=\sum_{j=0}^k\|D^ju\|_{L^2}^2.$$
Question: Could someone explain in a bit more detail how the above proof works, i.e. how the alleged convergence is supposed to happen without knowing more about the sequence of eigenvalues?
Thoughts: Applied to the above decomposition of $s$, the right-hand side becomes
$$\sum_{j=0}^k\sum_\lambda|\lambda|^{2j}\|s_\lambda\|_{L^2}^2.$$
Let's say we take $\lambda\geq 1$. Then we are concerned with estimating the term
$$\sum_\lambda|\lambda|^k\|s_\lambda\|_{L^2}^2,$$
where the summand is of the form given in Roe's proof. However, knowing only that $\|s_\lambda\|_{L^2}$ decays as $O(\lambda)^{-k}$ for all $k$ does not seem enough to guarantee the convergence of this sum, without knowing more about the distribution of $\lambda$ at least. (I could of course be misinterpreting something and would appreciate a quick pointer if that's the case!)

$|s_\lambda|=O(|\lambda|^{-\ell})$ for every $\ell$, in particular, for $\ell=(k+2)/2$ for your fixed $k$ so that the series converges.

@JochenWengenroth: I think the OP is asking the following, let's be explicit and enumerate the eigenvalues as $\lambda_m$ with $\lambda_m \leq \lambda_{m+1}$. How does one ensure that there exists some $s$ such that $\sum_m (\lambda_m)^{-s}$ converges? For example, why is it ruled out that $\lambda_m = \ln(3+m)$? For the Laplace-Beltrami of a compact manifold this is given by Weyl's law, but I don't know what is available for general 1st order elliptic operators.

The question mentioned in my previous comment appears to be known, based on this comment. A quick reading of the linked paper suggests that $\lambda_m$ grows likes $m^\alpha$ for some positive power $\alpha$, which would imply what is needed. It would be good if someone more expert can post a vetted answer.
